# Send Web Page in Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, html

I need to open /load / display web page in email   (not to send html of page in email) like iframe (not wokring in email). Also wanted to enable `JS` in it.

From my research / knowledge , i didn't found any possible ways, but is there any hack , that might possible to make this happen.

Please help me on this.

Comment: The page wouldn't display correctly in an email as many CSS rules aren't supported and elements wont display as you'd expect. Did you intend to send it as an attachment instead?

Comment: Thankfully JavaScript and other scripting languages do not work in any email clients, for obvious security and user sanity reasons!

Comment: @meghana does one of the answers qualify as an answer? Please mark it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible to display a website in most email clients like you described:

- referenced resources CSS and Images will not be available in most email clients
- most email clients wont run javascript

As a workaround you will be able to send an html email with the styles embedded. Once a client downloades the images (mostly after asking the user to do so) you will have your html email pretty much like a webpage in the email client.

Comment: @meghana your updated questions yields the same answer. Its not possible. Change your approach and send a propper html email instead of looking for "hacks". They will get you nowhere fast.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here - How To send Webpage as Email Message:
[How To send Webpage as Email Message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881528/how-to-send-webpage-as-email-message/6881546#6881546)

You need to put your style inline or in the head of the web page. also obviously javascript wont work and if you use images you need to use the full url.

Comment: Whilst that would work, what you would get in the email would like look nothing like the original webpage.

Comment: You might need to put your style inline or in the head of the web page. also obviously javascript wont work and if you use images you need to use the full url.

Comment: Thanks @kleinohad, for your reply. but i need to send whole web page itself , not by grabbing its html. and also want to enable js. :(